# Mockk mocking Java "enum" singleton

Tags: kotlin, mockk

I'm working in a project which has some Java legacy code. One common pattern there is to create singletons using the "enum" approach:

```
enum MySingleton {
   INSTANCE;

   int answer;
   init {
     answer = 42;
   }

   int fun1() { return answer };
```

This `INSTANCE` object in reality has some complex dependencies which I cannot fulfill during unit tests.  I thus would like to return a mocked `MySingleton` object whenever the caller uses `MySingleton.INSTANCE`. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes. https://mockk.io/#enumeration-mocks

Answer (score 1):

As per the official Mockk documentation, It can be done like below.

```
enum class Enumeration(val goodInt: Int) {
    CONSTANT(35),
    OTHER_CONSTANT(45);
}

mockkObject(Enumeration.CONSTANT)
every { Enumeration.CONSTANT.goodInt } returns 42
assertEquals(42, Enumeration.CONSTANT.goodInt)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can mock enums using `mockkObject(Enum)`